# Generate google-services.json for firebase via API

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Since we've upgraded from GCM to FCM we have a problem because the app suddenly needs a custom google-services.json and I don't seem to find a API or cli tool which enables me to add new apps and generate a new file.

Has someone found a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no API to generate a google-services.json. You can download it from your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) by selecting your project and then clicking to manage your Android app.

Comment: Also note that if you are only using FCM the google-services.json file is not absolutely necessary, you can define the required Sender ID string yourself.